# Match everything in quotes except specific pattern

Tags: regex

Is there a regex way to match around a specific pattern in a string? For example, I might have the string `"foo$(bar)baz"` and I might want to match `"foo` and `baz"` but not match `$(bar)`, since the last pattern (which is a macro in a string in my case and the expressions are used to color the matches in different colors in a custom language) will be matched later by a separate regex. Note that I want to match content exclusively in quotes and include the quotes in the match.

The use case is a custom programming language. This language can have string literals that contain macros (text surrounded by brackets and a dollar sign in front, like the jquery selectors).

Examples:
`"This is a $(macro)"`
`"$(macro)This is also a macro literal"`
`"This is a literal that does not have a macro and needs to be matched as well"`
`"$(This is a string literal that only contains a macro so only the quotes need to be matched)"`

And an example directly taken from the language: `SPRINTF("$(Vendor)")`

In these examples the values matched need to be everything except the `$(...)` part, because that part will be matched in turn by another expression. The matching is done so that the code highlighter I use can color the matches differently. Think of it like the code highlighting of javascript placeholders in strings surrounded by ` characters.

Edit: Changed `SPRINTF("test$(Vendor)")` to `SPRINTF("$(Vendor)")`.

Comment: Thing is, the matches in the quotes are not limited to `foo` or `baz`. They could be anything, but I just need to specifically filter out `$(...)` types of matches in quotes.

Comment: The use case is a custom programming language. This language can have string literals that contain macros (text surrounded by brackets and a dollar sign in front, like the jquery selectors).

Examples:
`"This is a $(macro)"`
`"$(macro)This is also a macro literal"`
`"This is a literal that does not have a macro and needs to be matched as well"`
`"$(This is a string literal that only contains a macro so only the quotes need to be matched)"`

And an example directly taken from the language:
`SPRINTF("test$(Vendor)")`

Comment: Edited as per requested, let me know if you need more context.

Comment: I handle one literal at a time. The expression gets passed to the highlighter and is handled to automatically detect all occurences in the code, regardless of position. So we only need it to work on one string literal.

Comment: Are you using javascript?

Comment: Yes, but the highlighter (Microsoft's Monaco editor) accepts a pattern to search for and not a function.

Answer (score 1):

**Second attempt** (should work in all cases):

I'm not sure which regex engine is used for Microsoft's Monaco editor, but here  I'm using javascript regex:

```
/"((?!\$\([^)]*\)).)*(?=.*")|(?<=".*)(.(?<!\$\([^)]*\)))*"/g
```

**The regex will return 2 matches, one before the macro and one after.**

**Explanation**:
`"` - match a quote `"`

`(` - start a group

`(?!\$\([^)]*\))` - negative look ahead for `$(...)`

`.` - match any char

`)*` - repeat this group zero or more times

`(?=.*")` - look ahead for any characters and a quote

`|` - `OR`

`(?<=".*)` - look behind for a quote `"` and any char zero or more times

`(` - start a group

`.` - match any char

`(?<!\$\([^)]*\))` - negative look behind for `$(...)`

`)*` - repeat this group zero or more times

`"` - match a quote `"`

The regex uses the `global` flag.

I have created a test case for you, you can see the result and play with it here: [JSRegExpBuilder](https://bak-o-soft.dk/RegExp/JSRegExpBuilder/tivLzg)

Comment: This almost satisfies all my requirements, thank you. I noticed however that it also matches characters before or after the quotes. If we take the example of `SPRINTF("$(Vendor)")`, `SPRINTF(` and `)` are also included in the matches. I tried modifying the expression in order to figure out the solution by myself but couldn't find an answer.